# How to parse and modify a hardcoded GraphQL query in Java to enable pagination?

Tags: java, parsing, graphql

I have a hardcoded GraphQL query and a Java application. I read the query from a file and then send it as payload of a POST request constructed using `HttpRequest` and `HttpClient`.

This works fine as long as the resulting JSON contains all the data that I need.

When it doesn't, the resulting JSON contains a `cursor` value that I can use for getting the next page of data.

Now, in order to use the `cursor` value and request the next page, I need to add the value to my GraphQL query. This means I need to somehow parse the query, traverse it, locate where to insert a new argument and pass the `cursor` value with it.

Trying to use Gson and parsing the query fails because GraphQL is not a subset of JSON.

The list of [GraphQL tooling for Java](https://graphql.org/code/#java-kotlin) doesn't seem to contain any libraries that would parse raw GraphQL queries. In general it looks like devs only write GraphQL servers in Java but not clients.

What are my options aside from just treating the GraphQL query as an unparsed text file using something like `Scanner`?

(Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to Java.)

Comment: Can you share the sample code and queries of what you are trying to do ? You can also use apollo-client or netflix-dgs or some other client libraries for writing grapqhl clients in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`graphql-java`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.graphql-java/graphql-java/18.0/index.html) you can parse the query with the [`Parser`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.graphql-java/graphql-java/18.0/graphql/parser/Parser.html) without requiring any [`Schema`](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/schema) definition.

**Imports:**

```
import graphql.parser.Parser;
import graphql.language.Document;
import graphql.language.Field;
import graphql.language.OperationDefinition;
import graphql.language.AstPrinter;
```

```java
String query = "{ Book(id: \"1\") { name, genre } }";
Parser parser = new Parser(); 
Document document = parser.parseDocument(query);
System.out.println(document);
```

**Output:**

```
Document{
  definitions=[
    OperationDefinition{
      name='null',
      operation=QUERY,
      variableDefinitions=[],
      directives=[],
      selectionSet=SelectionSet{
        selections=[
          Field{
            name='Book',
            alias='null',
            arguments=[
              Argument{
                name='id',
                value=StringValue{value='1'}
              }
            ],
            directives=[],
            selectionSet=SelectionSet{
              selections=[
                Field{
                  name='name',
                  alias='null',
                  arguments=[],
                  directives=[],
                  selectionSet=null
                },
                Field{
                  name='genre',
                  alias='null',
                  arguments=[],
                  directives=[],
                  selectionSet=null
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

To get id arguments passed to book below code can be used

```java
System.out.println(
    (
     (Field)
     ((OperationDefinition)document.getDefinitions().get(0))
     .getSelectionSet()
     .getSelections()
     .get(0)
    )
    .getArguments()
);
```

**Output:**

```
[Argument{name='id', value=StringValue{value='1'}}]
```

To convert [`Document`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.graphql-java/graphql-java/18.0/graphql/language/Document.html) back to query you can use [`AstPrinter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.graphql-java/graphql-java/18.0/graphql/language/AstPrinter.html)

```
System.out.println(AstPrinter.printAst(document));
```

**Output:**

```
query {
  Book(id: "1") {
    name
    genre
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at it! The Parser API is really scary.

After transforming a Document though, how do I convert it back into a GraphQL query?

Comment: @JuraGorohovsky updated the answer please check.

Comment: Thanks for your help! After numerous attempts to construct a query object that would include a modified set of arguments using graphql-java's Parser API, I realized I've had enough, and... switched over to GitHub's REST API. Best decision so far.